# c++ pthread error: invalid use of non-static member function

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have  error: invalid use of non-static member function when I try to compile following code:

```
int main()
{
    data d;
    cta ce;
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, d.subscribe, NULL ); 
    pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, ce.startStrategy, NULL ); 
    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2,NULL);

    return 0;
}

// cta.cpp
// ...
static void* cta::startStrategy()
{
    std::cout<<"haha"<<std::endl;
}

// data.cpp
// ...
static void* data::subscribe()
{ 
  std::cout<<"haha"<<std::endl;
}
```

getting error:

```
main.cpp:38:52: error: invalid use of non-static member function
pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, d.subscribe, NULL ); 
                                                ^
main.cpp:39:60: error: invalid use of non-static member function
pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, ce.startStrategy, NULL );
```

however, a similar code snippet works pretty well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
  class Foo {
    public:
      static void func() {
        std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
      }
  };

  int main() {
    Foo ins;
    pthread_t pt;
    pthread_t pt1;
    pthread_create( &pt, NULL, ins.func, NULL );
    pthread_create( &pt1, NULL, ins.func, NULL );
    pthread_join(pt, NULL);
    pthread_join(pt1, NULL);
    return 0;
  }
```

it compile fine and prints "hi" twice, i wonder what could be wrong with my code, since I already changed from void to static void and follow the same pattern, why am I still getting non-static error?

Comment: We'll need to see the header file(s) that declare `data` and `cta`.

Comment: How are `cta::startStrategy` and `data::subscribe` declared in your `.h`?

Comment: I'd recommend using [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead of direct pthread calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not use `pthread`.  Use C++ `std::thread`, and achieve happiness.

Witness this:

```
std::thread t1(&data::subscribe, &d);
std::thread t2(&cta::start_strategy, &ce);
```

Second of all, the most likely cause of your problem is that `static` modifier should be used in class definition (.h file), not in function definition outside of class.

Answer (score -2):

If you're going to use `pthread_create`, you have to pass it the parameters it wants. The start routine is `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`. Notice that there's nothing about any member function in there, `static` or otherwise. So the code is incorrect, even if it happens to work on some platform.